# E1CB mechanism with replacement of hydrogen step?

Tags: elimination

In [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/153094/80950) by Jay, one of the sub parts of the total question has the following reaction identified as $\ce{E1CB}$ pathway:
$$\ce{Ph-CH2-CH2Br} \text{ on treatment with } \ce{C2H5OD/C2H5O-}  \\
\text{gives } \ce{Ph-CD=CH2} \text{ as the major product.} $$

Now, I know $\ce{E1CB}$ mechanism to be an elimination mechanism which involves strong base and weak LG which I found well illustrated in the following example:

> [image]
>
> From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1cB-elimination_reaction#/media/File:E1cB_reaction_mechanism_with_leaving_group_LG.svg)

In extrapolating the above scheme into the question's case, I can't understand the reaction at all. Firstly $\ce{Br}$ is a good leaving group, if $\ce{E_1CB}$ is to happen, I think it must be taken that $\ce{Ph}$ is the leaving group. Secondly, let's leave the leaving group part and focus on the hydrogens, how did the hydrogen turn into a deuterium in the final product?

I have seen the user TRC's answer where they simply claim it is because of the strong base, I feel the logic is flawed, since it could have been $\ce{E_2}$ as well in that case due to the bromine existing. So, I don't find the argument fully convincing.

Comment: The question is ambiguous for lab purpose. But in theory you should read first 2 comments of TRC below his answer. E1cb mechanism can only produce carbanion intermediate.

Comment: I agree with @Jay - questions like these are only good in theory. In practice you will of course have E2 as well - which will give the non-deuterium elimination product. My answer was only in accordance to the scenario given in the question itself, the only possible reason to explain both the reactant, reagent and *already given* product.

Comment: [This](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2020/02/11/e1cb-elimination-unimolecular-conjugate-base/) would be a good read to understand the difference.