Hydration of Aldehydes and Ketones
Why does water not attack a carbonyl group as effectively as hydroxide ion ($\ce{OH-}$), and why does protonation of the carbonyl group increase the electrophilicity to a level that allows water to act as a nucleophile? Why is the resonance structure $\ce{C+-O-}$ not sufficient to make water act as a nucleophile? What is the difference between $\ce{C+-OH}$ and $\ce{C+-O-}$?

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

If my request for clarification was rejected or closed, why was it approved? I posted this because, when learning about carbonyl compound reactions, I noticed that protonation of carbonyl oxygen is unnecessary for strong nucleophiles but needed for weak ones. I thoroughly research what I learn, unlike those who memorize without understanding. Despite extensive searching, I couldn’t find an answer. I believed this community would benefit chemistry enthusiasts like me. Your comment frustrated me as I didn’t expect such behavior in an academic community.

Your question showed a rigidity or lack of flexibility in thinking. The answer is there in the question. Also a resonance form is a perturbation of a canonical structure not an entity in itself. A carbonyl is a weak Lewis acid-base that reacts gently with weak Lewis acids or bases and more vigorously with stronger Lewis acids or  bases. The protonated carbonyl is an actual entity. The resonance structure is a perturbation in this context or possibly an excited electronic state in another.

Your effort of defending your question should be rather invested in its improvement. E.g. put in your own thoughts why it could be, if you could not find anything. Questions consisting of just list of questions are considered as bad ones on most of StackExchange sites and are usually quickly closed. Academic community would have even more strict approach than SE sites, that are more benevolent to users than scientific magazines to paper submitters.

Review e.g. search results for  site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org  hydroxide water nucleophile carbonyl

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152737/the-dependency-on-electron-density-in-the-reactivity-order-of-electrophilic-and
